# OpenCV - APIs Locations Aren't Document?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

Maybe I've been spoiled by MSDN, but I'm tearing my hair out looking for which DLLs the APIs are located in.  It's driving me crazy to the point, I've started about to write some code that will walk the DLL export table so I can find the function!!

Like on MSDN, if I need a Windows function, eg, GetModuleHandle().  I go to the MSDN page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx

And it tells me exactly where the function resides:

```
Library - Kernel32.lib
DLL - Kernel32.dll
```

Now for OpenCV, I'm looking for which library and DLL the function cvCreateKalman() resides in.  I simply cannot find it in their documentation.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV docs don't have that info, unfortunately, but on Windows you can use [`dumpbin`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177429) to list all the exported symbols of a DLL:

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS libopencv_core.dll
```

Which is pretty much what [`nm`](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/linux-nm-command/) does for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV documentation is divided to modules.
http://opencv.itseez.com/index.html

serach for 'Kalman' and you will find that it's inside the 'video' module.

note that it changes between versions, so if you use older version look here:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

Comment: But even these docs on modules are not complete. For instance, what's inside opencv_ts? There's only one video module in the doc, but I see opencv_video and opencv_videostab libraries, what's up with that? The docs are lacking this sort of information, so +1 to the question.